# Deno bundle replacement

Tags: typescript, bundle, deno, esbuild

Could you please help me with replacing deprecetad `deno bundle` command?

I wanted to change it for esbuild, but running a command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/esbuild --bundle lib/commands/abc/main.ts --outfile=mod.abc.ts
```

give me an error:

```
[ERROR] Top-level await is currently not supported with the "iife" output format
```

I have tried also with `--format=cjs` and `--format=esm` option, but the output still is different than `deno bundle` output. eg. there are not imports included.

How should I use it?

Or maybe can you help me with other option? The goal is to quickly remove `deno bundle` without main code modification.

Answer (score 2):

**The esbuild CLI interface does not support bundling of Deno TypeScript module code** (at least when using remote imports — e.g. `https://deno.land/...`).

The JavaScript API for esbuild can handle those imports by using a plugin that's maintained by one of the Deno core team members: https://github.com/lucacasonato/esbuild_deno_loader

The readme for the plugin explains its usage, and the JavaScript API for esbuild is extensively documented as well: https://esbuild.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

There are three recommended replacements for `deno bundle` in in the current Deno version v1.32.3:

```
Warning "deno bundle" is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
Use alternative bundlers like "deno_emit", "esbuild" or "rollup" instead.
```

See:

- https://github.com/denoland/deno_emit
- https://esbuild.github.io/
- https://rollupjs.org/

If esbuild doesn't work then you may check the other ones. Also, esbuild has a project deno-esbuild that might be relevant:

- https://github.com/esbuild/deno-esbuild

Rollup has some instructions abut Deno usage:

- https://rollupjs.org/tools/#deno

deno_emit is the most Deno-centric from those three - it has similar functionality as the removed `Deno.emit()` but as a user loadable module, to avoid including its code in the main Deno binary. In principle it should be the most similar to the `deno bundle` but I'm not sure how stable it is already.

Answer (score 0):

## **Straightforward solution to bundle *Deno Typescript* for the *browser* in *2024*:**

### 1. Create a new file: `bundle.ts`

Make sure to update `entryPoints` and `outdir`.

```js
import * as esbuild from "https://deno.land/x/esbuild@v0.20.1/mod.js";
import { denoPlugins } from "jsr:@luca/esbuild-deno-loader@0.9";

esbuild.build({
  plugins: [...denoPlugins()],
  entryPoints: ["<input>/<dir>/script.ts"],
  outdir: "<output>/<dir>/",
  bundle: true,
  platform: "browser",
  format: "esm",
  target: "esnext",
  minify: true,
  sourcemap: true,
  treeShaking: true,
});
await esbuild.stop();
```

### 2. Run it!

`deno run --allow-read --allow-write --allow-env --allow-net --allow-run bundle.ts`

You can create a [`deno task`](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/tools/task_runner) to make running this easier. Add this to your `deno.jsonc`:

```json
{
  "tasks": {
    "bundle": "deno run --allow-read --allow-write --allow-env --allow-net --allow-run bundle.ts"
  }
}
```

#### Helpful resources:

- [`esbuild`](https://deno.land/x/esbuild@v0.20.1) ([git](https://github.com/esbuild/deno-esbuild))

  - [`.build()`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#build)
  - [`entryPoints: []`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#entry-points)
  - [`outdir`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#outdir)
  - [`bundle: true`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#bundle)
  - [`platform: "browser"`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#platform)
  - [`format: "esm"`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#format-esm)
  - [`target: "esnext"`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#target)
  - [`minify: true`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#minify)
  - [`sourcemap: true`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#sourcemap)
  - [`treeShaking: true`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#tree-shaking)
- [`esbuild-deno-loader`/`denoPlugins`](https://jsr.io/@luca/esbuild-deno-loader) ([deno.land/x](https://deno.land/x/esbuild_deno_loader@0.9.0/mod.ts)) ([git](https://github.com/lucacasonato/esbuild_deno_loader))

  - This is necessary if your input `.ts` files include import statements with Deno module specifiers like `file:`, `https:`, `data:`, `npm:`, and/or `jsr:`.

---

For more context, check out my post on this topic: https://www.toddgriffin.me/blog/how-to-bundle-deno-typescript-for-the-browser